# How to retrieve the list of positions including all the fields using the LinkedIn javascript sdk?

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

I want to get the id, title, summary, start-date, end-date, is-current and company name for each position that a LinkedIn member has entered on its profile.

I tested a query on the [REST Console](https://apigee.com/console/linkedin) and I got the desired result. The query is "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/positions:(id,title,summary,start-date,end-date,is-current,company)?format=json".

The problem is that when I try to do the same thing using the LinkedIn javascript SDK I'm not getting the whole list of fields for each position. I'm getting the complete list of positions, but not all the fields for each position.

This is the call that I'm doing with the javascript SDK:

```
//in this function I'm specifying the list of fields that I want to retrieve for each position
//but I'm getting only some fields (id, start-date and end-date)
function getProfileData() {
        IN.API.Raw("/people/~/positions:(id,title,summary,start-date,end-date,is-current,company)?format=json").result(onSuccess).error(onError);
}
```

Somebody has any idea of what I need to do to get the same result than using the REST Console?

Answer (score 0):

Requesting URL is wrong.

Use following for positions

> https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,positions)?format=json

Use following for locations

> https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,location)?format=json

Comment: The answer is not working. I tried i got  this result returned :  {
  "id": "wQplQQjzLa",
  "positions": {"_total": 0}
} as my code was :     function getProfileData() {
        IN.API.Raw("/people/~:(id,positions)?format=json").result(onSuccess).error(onError);
    }

Comment: See the documentation it's there and it worked for me.
https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields/basic-profile

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve your profile data use this,

```
   IN.API.Profile("me")
        .fields([
                "firstName","lastName","headline","positions:(company,title,summary,startDate,endDate,isCurrent)","industry",
                "location:(name,country:(code))","pictureUrl","publicProfileUrl","emailAddress",
                "educations","dateOfBirth"])
        .result(onSuccess)
        .error(onError);
```

**(or)** If you want to retrieve other profile data then replace "`me`" with "`<public profile url>`"

```
   IN.API.Profile("url=https://nl.linkedin.com/in/williamhgates")
        .fields([
                "firstName","lastName","headline","positions:(company,title,summary,startDate,endDate,isCurrent)","industry",
                "location:(name,country:(code))","pictureUrl","publicProfileUrl","emailAddress",
                "educations","dateOfBirth"])
        .result(onSuccess)
        .error(onError);
```