# How to fetch profile details of another user using LinkedIn Javascript API, if we have profile id of that user

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

I know how to fetch the profile details of a logged in user using LinkedIn Javascript SDK. Is it possible to fetch the user profile details for another user if i have his unique profile id extracted from his profile url.

This is my profile url: https://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=628744xx

soc_id = 628744xx

This is my code:

```
document_obj.on('click', '[id^=linkedInDetailsBtn_]', function(e) {
        //check whether user is logged in LinkedIn else popup login
        IN.User.authorize(function() {
    var v_id = jQuery(this).attr('srch'),soc_id=jQuery(this).attr('soc_id'),link='';
    if(soc_id == "" || soc_id == undefined){
        link = jQuery('#s_link_'+v_id).attr('href');
        var aLinkObj = link.split('?id=');
        soc_id =  aLinkObj[1];
        IN.API.Raw("/people/id="+soc_id)
        .method("GET")
        .result(function(result) {
          console.log(result);
        })
        .error(function error(e) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(e.message));
        });
        return false;
    }
});
    });
```

Comment: check this.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28686754/how-to-retrieve-the-list-of-positions-including-all-the-fields-using-the-linkedi/35269633#35269633

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
GET: https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/id=[member_id]

A comprehensive list of all the profile related REST APIs are available [here](https://developer-programs.linkedin.com/documents/profile-api)

Comment: Hi thanks for you reply i have edited my question and code with your help but its giving invalid member id error for GET Request.

Comment: sorry but where we specify the profile id "628744xx" in that GET request... i need to fetch data for users based on their profile id from profile url... is it possible via REST API.... loggedin user details are getting via API but i need to fetch other user's profile data using profile id.